# Can "to proximate" be a verb meaning 'to place close'?

Tags: word-usage

Can *[to] proximate* be a verb with the meaning 'to place close'?

I can't find a reference for this usage, even in remarkably comprehensive [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proximate) (more headwords than OED), but I have heard it.

Among examples on the internet are:

> - *Generally, it is a “bottom-up” approach that uses building features to proximate the material stocks of individual buildings*

[[Yuan et al; Wiley Online Library](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/jiec.13348)]

> - *If nerve ends retract, there is no spontaneous regeneration and grafts are required to proximate the nerve ends and give continuity to*
>   *the nerve.*

[[Escobar et al; ProQuest](https://www.proquest.com/openview/5cc46cb4bce039ca2465fa60b789d6ba/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=2032349)]

Comment: Have you tried the dictionary?

Comment: @alphabet: online dictionaries fail to include the verbal form. do u think people post here for fame?

Comment: Then doesn't that answer your question? No, it can't be used as a verb.

Comment: The full (subscription-only) OED has **proximate** v. intransitive. *To approach, come near. Also transitive: to locate or bring near. Frequently with to.* Their most recent citation: *1997   V. Flieger Question of Time iv. 98   This conversation is held on a river, thus physically proximating the actuality of water to what appears to be the metaphor of time.*

Comment: I've never heard this use of the word. Maybe you're confusing with "approximate", which can be a verb.

Comment: It's certainly relatively *rarely* used as a verb. I just searched Google Books for ***proximating*** within C21, and had to wade through at least 20 false positives from hyphenated ***ap-proximating*** before I found the first actual match. But matches do exist, and it's in the OED, so there's your answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for your research. I will mark it as accepted if you put it as answer. I have only heard a person verbally use it and he was unsure if it was correct himself.

Comment: I thought someone would find it in an open-access online dictionary, in which case it's Off Topic. But maybe it's only in the subscription-only OED. And given how tricky it was to actually find valid instances in Google Books, I guess the Q is sound.

Comment: It is a verb, but not really one that means *to place close*. I'd try *situate*, as in *situate the house next to the barn*.

Comment: It's always useful to mention *where* you heard something, even if you can only remember general details (e.g. country).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full (subscription-only) OED has...

> **proximate** verb intransitive
> *To approach, come near.*
> Also transitive
> *to locate or bring near. Frequently with **to.***
> Their most recent citation:
> 1997 V. Flieger Question of Time iv. 98
> *This conversation is held on a river, thus physically proximating the actuality of water to what appears to be the metaphor of time.*

It's certainly relatively rarely used as a verb. I just searched Google Books for ***proximating*** within C21, and had to wade through at least 20 false positives (from hyphenated ***ap-proximating***) before I found the first actual match. But matches do exist, and it's in the OED, so it *is* a verb.

---

It may be worth pointing out that the above definition *only* licenses the verb in contexts involving ***physical, spatial*** proximity. But apart from "medical, anatomical" contexts (bodily organs being moved closer by surgery, for example), almost all the "non-false positive" C21 references I found in Google Books were the ***approaching in value / amount*** sense - which is probably always "misuse".

Comment: Flieger's sentence -- maybe someday I will understand it.

Comment: A river as a *concept* often occurs in literature / poetry as a metaphor for time (think: *You can never step into the same river twice*). The conversation was probably somehow related to time, but the point is the conversation and the river were "brought together".

Comment: '_Physically_ proximating' a _metaphor_? Worse than _me and my shadow_. Yesterday, I literally collided with a catachresis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't like the example. But I don't like the verb anyway, and I wasn't keen on any of the other half-dozen OED cites. Best of a bad bunch was 1795: *Some farmers **proximated** to rookeries do assert, that the rooks destroy seven times as much more grain.*

Comment: Farmers who proximate to rookeries shouldn't make avian assertions.

Comment: A fair number of examples  turn up if you search ["to proximate the"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+proximate+the%22&nfpr=1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AB5stBgqZIgRWw6hHWFkoWJfUdjsDVKA0Q:1689258882951&ei=gguwZOPVOfjm5NoPuYOukAQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjjnpvd84uAAxV4M1kFHbmBC0IQ8NMDegQIDxAW&biw=1127&bih=576&dpr=1) or "to proximate these" in Google books.

Comment: @DjinTonic: The first three non false positive matches from your search all look to me like they should have been ***approximate*** anyway (in the sense of *[create / give rise to] **very similar** [conditions]*, rather than anything to do with physical proximity

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, some do, but some appear to mean to approach/come close to something in quantity rather than approximate it.

Comment: @DjinTonic: I see what you mean. But the OED definitions all seem to concern ***physical*** proximity, rather than ***nearly** the same **value***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've put some examples from medicine in an answer.

Comment: ...whereas the adjectival sense of ***proximate cause*** isn't *directly* concerned with physical proximity - it's more to do with an "event" in time, that's *closely related* to something that happens later.

Answer (score 1):

Examples from Google Books follow. This meaning appears to still be in use in medicine and dentistry.

It is much more common to say you ***ap***proximate the edges of a wound.

> The thing we are endeavoring to do is not have them separate, but to
> **proximate** these two ends of the wedge so that the ankle bone could bend normally without side motion. [B. F. Skinner; *Verbal
> Behavior*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Verbal_Behavior/IERGCk2OyacC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20proximate%20these%22&pg=RA14-PA179&printsec=frontcover) (1957)

> Devices vary as to the best approach to insert the blade (or stat) in
> the patient's mouth and to **proximate** the larynx. [N. Jagannathan;
> *Management of the Difficult Pediatric Airway*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Management_of_the_Difficult_Pediatric_Ai/1oK0DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20proximate%20the%22&pg=PA70&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> But I believe it can very well be explained on the ground that he has
> no index finger to constantly proximate that thumb to, and
> consequently instead of using those muscles ordinarily to **proximate** the thumb to the index finger. [Lentz v. Mumy Well Service](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lentz_v_Mumy_Well_Service_340_MICH_1_195/t7gGCCE9uOgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22But%20I%20believe%20it%20can%20very%20well%20be%20explained%20on%20the%20ground%20that%20he%20has%20no%20index%20finger%20to%20constantly%20proximate%20that%20thumb%20to,%20and%20consequently%20instead%20of%20using%20those%20muscles%20ordinarily%22&pg=PA98&printsec=frontcover)
> (1954)

> Dr. Woo testified that he elected to attempt to **proximate** the
> wound at that time in order to help the healing. [California
> Court of Appeal](https://www.google.com/books/edition/California_Court_of_Appeal_1st_Appellate/QZxPaLtm89wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20proximate%20the%22&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: These "medical, anatomical" contexts seem more suited to the word. Of course, anatomy is much concerned with distinguishing ***proximal*** and ***distal***, which terms don't occur anywhere near as often in many other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

> Can [to] proximate be a verb with the meaning 'to place close'?

The answer is "Yes, **but**..."

**To proximate** (OED) =  *intransitive.* **To approach, come near.** Also *transitive:* **to locate or bring near.** Frequently with *to* has been around since the 17th century **but** it is a relatively rare word and infrequently used or recognised as such phrases as "approach or come near" are far more idiomatic.

There is also the danger of confusion with the verb "to approximate".

I suggest that you do not use it.

Comment: FF has already given this.